# How to remove rows in Pandas DataFrame that are partial duplicates?

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have a DataFrame of scraped tweets, and I am trying to remove the rows of tweets that are partial duplicates.

Below is a simplified DataFrame with the same issue. Notice how the first and the last tweet have all but the attached url ending in common; I need a way to drop partial duplicates like this and only keep the latest instance.

```
data = {
    'Tweets':[' The Interstate is closed www.txdot.com/closed',\
                'The project is complete www.txdot.com/news',\
                'The Interstate is closed www.txdot.com/news'],
    'Date': ['Mon Aug 03 20:48:42', 'Mon Aug 03 20:15:42', 'Mon Aug 03 20:01:42' ]
}

df =pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I've tried dropping duplicates with the drop_duplicates method below, but there doesn't seem to an argument to accomplish this.

```
 df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Tweets'])
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice in a row just because you didn't get a response the first time.

Comment: What is the exact criteria to consider them as duplicates? once you know what you want to do then we can program it

Comment: @ansev Duplicates would be tweets that have identical text even though their urls are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write a regex to remove the slash identify each column by the main url portion and ignore the forward slash.

```
df['Tweets'].replace('(www\.\w+\.com)/(\w+)',r'\1',regex=True).drop_duplicates()
```

Yields

```
0    The Interstate is closed www.txdot.com
1     The project is complete www.txdot.com
Name: Tweets, dtype: object
```

we can pass the index and create a boolean filter.

```
df.loc[df['Tweets'].replace('(www\.\w+\.com)/(\w+)',r'\1',regex=True).drop_duplicates().index]


                                          Tweets                 Date
0  The Interstate is closed www.txdot.com/closed  Mon Aug 03 20:48:42
1     The project is complete www.txdot.com/news  Mon Aug 03 20:15:42
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.